# How do the Flowfiles get distributed across the cluster nodes?

Tags: apache-nifi

For example, if I have a GetFile processor that I have designated to be isolated, how do the flow files coming from that processor get distributed across the cluster nodes?

Is there any additional work / processors that need to be added?

Comment: Processors can be scheduled to only run on the Primary node in a cluster. Processsors like `GetFile` should definitely have this option checked so that you don't get duplicate data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Apache NiFi today the question of load balancing across the cluster has two main answers.  First, you must consider how data gets to the cluster in the first place.  Second, once it is in the cluster do you need to rebalance.

For getting data into the cluster it is important that you select protocols which are themselves scalable in nature.  Protocols which offer queuing semantics are good for this whereas protocols which do not offer queuing semantics are problematic.  As an example of one with queueing semantics think JMS queues or Kafka or some HTTP APIs.  Those are great because one or more clients can pull from them in a queue fashion and thus spread the load.  An example of a protocol which does not offer such behavior would bet GetFile or GetSFTP and so on.  These are problematic because the client(s) have to share state about which data they see to pull.  To address even these protocols we've moved to a model of 'ListSFTP' and 'FetchSFTP' where ListSFTP occurs on one node in the cluster (primary node) and then it uses Site-to-Site feature of NiFi to load balance to the rest of the cluster then each node gets its share of work and does FetchSFTP to actually pull the data.  The same pattern is offered for HDFS now as well.

In describing that pattern I also mentioned Site-to-Site.  This is how two nifi clusters can share data which is great for Inter-site and Instra-Site distribution needs.  It also works well for spreading load within the same cluster.  For this you simply send the data to the same cluster and NiFi takes care then of load balancing and fail-over and detection of new nodes and removed nodes.

So there are great options already.  That said we can do more and in the future we plan to offer a way for you to on a connection indicate it should be auto-load-balanced and then it will behind the scenes do what I've described.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Great info, Joe. We finally figured out the Site to Site.  Thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated answer, that works even simpler with newer versions of NiFi. I am running Apache NiFi 1.8.0 here.

The approach I found here is to use a processor on the primary node, that will emit flow files to be consumed via a load balanced connection.

For example, use one of the `List*` processors, in "Scheduling" set its "Execution" to run on the primary node.

[image]

This should feed into the next processor. Select the connection and set its "Load Balance Strategy".

[image]

You can read more about the feature in its [design document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Load-Balanced+Connections).